# How is this binomial coefficient be written in this way?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    p\\
    n\end{pmatrix}=\frac{p!}{n!(p-n)!} = \frac{p(p-1)(p - 2) \dots (p-(n-1))}{n!}$$

I was reviewing and going over the binomial theorem. While doing that, I came across this binomial coefficient and began to feel confused about how it simplifies to the result on the right-hand side. What is the process behind this simplification?

Comment: develop $p!$ and $(p-n)!$ can you cancel some terms two by two between numerator and denominator ? E.g $p=5$ and $n=2$ then $\frac{5!}{3!}=\frac{5.4.3.2.1}{3.2.1}=5.4$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) going forward to use mathjax, instead of using images.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify $p !$ with $(p - n)!:$ $$\frac{p!}{(p-n)!} = \frac{(p - n)! (p - n + 1) \dots (p - 1) p}{(p - n)!} = (p - n + 1) \dots (p - 1) p,$$ which yields the result.

Comment: Where does the expression $(p-n+1)$ come from?

Comment: Okay, let me ask you this: what is $p!$?

Comment: $p!=p(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)(p-4)...$

Comment: yes, or you could write $p! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot (p - n - 1) \cdot (p - n) \cdot (p - n + 1) \cdot (p - n + 2) \cdot \dots \cdot (p - 2) \cdot (p - 1) \cdot p.$

Answer (score 0):

See, leaving out the n! in the denominator for now

$$\begin{split}\frac{p!}{(p-n)!}&=\frac{p*(p-1)*(p-2)*...*(p-n+1)*(p-n)*(p-n-1)*...*2*1}{(p-n)*(p-n-1)*...*2*1}\\
&=p*(p-1)*(p-2)*...*(p-(n-2))*(p-(n-1))\end{split}$$

Divide by the original n! to achieve

$$\frac{p*(p-1)*(p-2)*...*(p-(n-2))*(p-(n-1))}{n!}$$

Basically, it truncates p! to the first p - (p-(n-1)) + 1 terms

Comment: If we consider the example with $p=5$ and $n=3$, wouldn’t $p-2=(p-n+1)$ since $5-2=5-3+1=3$? Then what's the point of having both? Sorry for my ignorance, but this is what it looks like to me. Thanks.

Comment: The formulas capture the spirit and don't work for certain cases as you mentioned, e.g. if p and n are too close, or if p is too small.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying. Essentially, the expressions represent the process generally and obviously with numbers it would turn out to be less tedious. This 'derivation' is generally outlining what happens. Is that what you mean? @Stacker

Comment: Yes, if p=5,n=3, you find that $${5 \choose 2}=\frac{5!}{2!3!}=\frac{5*4}{2*1}$$